# Apex FLS Methods

Tags: apex, security, fls

I have a question regarding Salesforce FLS.

Is there any method available which dynamic check the object field-level security.
Like I have Account object and Field name Phone and pass to any available method in Apex which returns true or false based on the profile permission

**Pseudocode**

boolean method (objectname, fieldname){

return objectname.fieldname.isacceible();

}

Just FYI: I don't want to keep the field in the String Map like an example given in salesforce documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_crud_fls.htm

Comment: What is your specific objection to using a `Map`? It's a pretty firm requirement if you want this code to work dynamically.

Comment: I have more than 500 fields on the object and for every time a single field, I don't want to keep the map for all fields.

Comment: You don't need to construct it yourself...again, what is your *specific objection*?

Answer (score 1):

if what you want to do is to make sure that you don't send around fields that the user does not have access to, check out the [Strip Inaccessible](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_with_security_stripInaccessible.htm) functionality

```
SObjectAccessDecision securityDecision = Security.stripInaccessible(sourceRecords);
Contact c = securityDecision.getRecords()[0];
System.debug(c.isSet('social_security_number__c')); // prints "false"
System.debug(JSON.serialize(c)); // will not display the social_security_number__c information
```

Comment: This not work for me because my object and field both are dynamic, I already check this. like Security.SObjectAccessDecision securityDecision = Security.stripInaccessible(
    AccessType.READABLE, Sobject
); this give me error Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void stripInaccessible(System.AccessType, SObject) from the type System.Security

Comment: @Faisal, You need to pass a list of sObjects, even if the list only contains one record. For example `Security.SObjectAccessDecision securityDecision = Security.stripInaccessible( AccessType.READABLE, new List<sObject>{Sobject} );`

Comment: you are right but in my case, I have only one record and get the object instance dynamically sobject sObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objName).newSObject(recordId);

Comment: It doesn't matter how you get the sObject, just pass it through. Maybe its clearer for you like this `Security.SObjectAccessDecision securityDecision = Security.stripInaccessible( AccessType.READABLE, new List<sObject/*stays as sObject to indicate that is a generic one*/>{whateverYourSobjectVariableIs} );` The method accepts a List of any sObject, regardless if you know the type or not. Regardless if you query or instantiate it dynamically.